# Context Menu in Custom Component

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm building my a custom component where i want to have a context menu on. So far i've succesfully created and shown the context menu doing the following:

```
public class CustomComponent extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener, OnCreateContextMenuListener   {

private final MenuInflater menuInflator;

public CustomComponent(final Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomComponent(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    menuInflator = new MenuInflater(context);

    final LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    inf.inflate(R.layout.component, this, true);

    setOnClickListener(this);
    setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menuInflator.inflate(R.menu.menu_context, menu);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    showContextMenu();
}
```

}

The problem i'm facing now is that i don't know how to get the onContextItemSelected() function to be called inside this component. I was looking through some source in Activity and noticed that it has a mWindow member that holds these callbacks. I'm not really sure if it is possible to it this way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after searching for other options i found a very simpel solutions:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menuInflator.inflate(R.menu.menu_context, menu);
    menu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    // Do something
    return false;
}
```

ofcouse you need to implement OnMenuItemClickListener for this to work